# Font and Element Sizing Options

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have come to the understanding that Pt should be used if you want something to be printed. Easy enough. Px could be used due to its ability to scale with a browsers zoom function, but for the most part frowned upon.

My confusion comes in in regards to % and ems. The below article, and most others I read, seem to suggest that ems is the way to go for the future. It seems crazy though that in order to get a specific size you would need something like 1.235em or 0.675em.

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs

The article mentions to use percent to set the initial size of the cite to then make em easier? This does not make since to me.

Ultimately my question is this, what limitations or issues would I run into if I were to only use percents to set my sizing? (Is the same true, em vs %, for sizing divs?) Any clarification that could be provide would be much appreciated. I feel that I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I know of is the browser client font size setting as mentioned in the article.

-> from a cross browser consistency point of view you might just stick to %.

Scaling the initial font size using % gets you the advantage that 1em then equals that predifined size.

Maybe [this](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm) might help you.